# How does GitLab merge request with squash work under the hood?

Tags: git, gitlab

On a daily basis I am working with GitLab with following workflow:

1. I create a new `feature` branch from `main` branch
2. I commit and push changes to the `feature` branch
3. Then I create a new merge request (from `feature` into `main`) via GitLab GUI using `squash` feature:
   [image]
4. When approver accept my MR, it results with following `main` branch tree (from IntellJ IDEA):
   [image]

I have tried to achieve the same on my testing repository using command line only but with no success so far. I have tried (on `feature` branch) interactive rebase as well as soft reset with force push but it always results as a 'single line tree'. Example after two separate merges from `feature` into `main`:

```
git checkout main
git merge <feature_branch_name>
```

[image]

Does anyone know how it works under the hood (command by command)? According to [this issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/issues/49046) it uses soft reset but it's only someone's guess. I was also searching in official documentation but with no success so far. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use merge without fast-forward:

```
git merge --no-ff
```

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#Documentation/git-merge.txt---no-ff

This will create the merge as you want

You can make it the default

Put in your config file  ( `$HOME/.gitconfig` on linux)

```
[merge]
    ff = no
    commit = no
```

You can also use git-config to do this:

```
  git config --global merge.commit no
  git config --global merge.ff no
```